# Wordpress Theme Will Be Used or not In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Wordpress Theme Is made in Php and asp.net Run Bootstrap Theme.
But In Wordpress Bootstrap Is used To make Responsive theme?. Or Php will make Theme Responsive...

Comment: My Question is Is Wordpress Theme Is used Or Not In Asp.net?

Comment: Please refer this link https://gunnarpeipman.com/wordpress-on-dotnet-core/